Ignite reports OOM when we create large number of caches without any data
Apache Ignite throws OOM when we create huge number of caches without any data. Following are the configuration of data region:
Memory allocated: 1GB
Persistence enabled: False
Number of caches created: 500
It seems like for each cache there is a overhead of 5MB. Is this correct?
Note : If persistence is enabled we dont see this issue. This issue only happens when persistence is disabled

I don't know the exact number, but yes, that is expected behaviour. If your tables have a similar lifecycle, you can use cache groups to reduce the overhead. Cache Groups share some of their data structures.
